# Save a list after leaving the foreach loop

Tags: c#, list

So i am new to c# and i want to keep my list after leaving a loop....

```
             foreach (object itemChecked1 in clVorfahr.CheckedItems)
        {
             List<object> VorfahrCK = clVorfahr.CheckedItems.OfType<object>().ToList();

        }

        foreach (object itemChecked in clNachfolg.CheckedItems)
        {
             List<object> NachfolgCK = clNachfolg.CheckedItems.OfType<object>().ToList();
        }
```

After leaving this foreach loop my list is empty but when i debug and stop for each loop my list is getting data but after leaveing its completely empty

Comment: Take a step back and explain to us the underlying problem you are trying to solve with the loop.

Comment: Finding a good piece of docs on how variable declaration scopes work in C# is waay harder than I thought.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem consists of two parts:

1. You´re creating an entire new list on every iteration of `clVorfahr.CkeckedItems`.
2. you don´t assign that list to anything, thus you can´t do anything with the list(s) when iteration was done.

So you should  *create* the list *outside* the loop and *fill* it *within*:

```
List<object> VorfahrCK = new List<object>();
foreach (object itemChecked1 in clVorfahr.CheckedItems)
{
    VorfahrCK.Add(itemChecked);
}
```

The following is a bit shorter but does the same:

```
List<object> VorfahrCK = clVorfahr.CheckedItems.OfType<object>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is confused

1, scope defined your variable in the loop so thats the place it exists, to make it exist outside the loop declare it before - do the loop and then you can use it after.

2, in your loop for each item you do exactly the same not add an item to the list..

you would have gotten away with just the line

```
List<object> NachfolgCK = clNachfolg.CheckedItems.OfType<object>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Initialise them outside of the loop, otherwise they are not in the scope that you require!

```
 List<object> VorfahrCK = new List<object>();
 List<object> NachfolgCK = new List<object>();

    foreach (object itemChecked1 in clVorfahr.CheckedItems)
    {
         VorfahrCK = clVorfahr.CheckedItems.OfType<object>().ToList();

    }

    foreach (object itemChecked in clNachfolg.CheckedItems)
    {
         NachfolgCK = clNachfolg.CheckedItems.OfType<object>().ToList();
    }
```

Comment: But hes not using the loop object just repeating say the same initialization 1000 times

Comment: it does seem like a weird thing to do

Answer (score 0):

You declare those variables inside `foreach` brackets. Therefore, they are scoped in the 2 brackets.
Declare them outside like below:

```
List<object> VorfahrCK = new List<object>();
foreach (object itemChecked1 in clVorfahr.CheckedItems)
    {
         VorfahrCK = clVorfahr.CheckedItems.OfType<object>().ToList();

    }
```

But I don't see you use `itemChecked1` anyway, why foreach?

Anyway, I usually use stuff like these:

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
foreach (var line in anotherStringList)
{
    stringList.Add(line);
}
```